# Swift: Unable to deallocate memory

Tags: swift, malloc, sigabrt

I am trying to write a method to resize an image captured in Swift, but in my function loop (which captures frames in real-time), I got an error that occurred after a few seconds of capture. I realized I wasn't deallocating memory, so I added defer statements to do so, but these defer statements throw malloc errors stating that I haven't allocated memory, but I think I have correctly allocated the memory. Thus, I am unable to deallocate the memory I am allocating.

I tried adding CVPixelBuffer(Un)LockBaseAddress statements, but that didn't do anything.

```swift
private func resizePixelBuffer(imageBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, scaleWidth: Int, scaleHeight: Int) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        guard let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer) else {return nil}
        let bytes_per_row = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)

        // Allocate input buffer
        var inBuff = vImage_Buffer(data: baseAddress, height: vImagePixelCount(height), width: vImagePixelCount(width), rowBytes: bytes_per_row)
        defer { free(inBuff.data) } // ADDED

        // Allocate output container
        let outData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: 4*scaleWidth*scaleHeight)
        defer { outData.deallocate() } // ADDED

        // Assign output buffer
        var outBuff = vImage_Buffer(data: outData, height: vImagePixelCount(scaleHeight), width: vImagePixelCount(scaleWidth), rowBytes: 4*scaleWidth)
        defer { free(outBuff.data) } // ADDED

        let releaseCallback: CVPixelBufferReleaseBytesCallback = {_, ptr in
            if let ptr = ptr {
                free(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: ptr))
            }
        }
        // Assign output data
        let error = vImageScale_ARGB8888(&inBuff, &outBuff, nil, vImage_Flags(kvImageHighQualityResampling))
        guard error == kvImageNoError else {return nil}
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

        ...
    }
```

`python-ios-integration(2477,0x16cf5f000) malloc: *** error for object 0x10e84c000: pointer being freed was not allocated; python-ios-integration(2477,0x16cf5f000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Comment: Have you considered checking out if there is a buffer that is manually deallocated multiple times? The deallocation in this code looks good to me.

Comment: Not manually, no. I don't use any other deallocations in this event loop. However this function is called every time a frame is captured, so would it be possible that it is being deallocated automatically? Though, that wouldn't explain the memory leak when I remove the deallocations...

Comment: I'm sceptical about the automatic deallocation, because in the docs at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer , it is stated that UnsafeMutablePointer provides no automatic memory management. If it's not what I guessed previously, I would look for the leak somewhere else. Have you tried using memory profilers to find some zombie objects, or recursive pointers?